# What is the difference between two types of velocity?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, definition, speed, calculus

What is the difference between $v=\frac{s}{\Delta t}$ and $\bar{v} =\frac{\Delta\bar{x}}{\Delta t}$, are they the same?

Comment: Should your first equation read $\frac{\Delta S}{\Delta t}$? It’s not clear what you are asking.

Comment: If S is the distance between two points, then yes. $\Delta s = s_2 - s_1$. And in your second equation, $\Delta \vec x = \vec x_2 - \vec x_1$. Both your equations are equivalent if this is the case, and also you use vector notation in your second equation and not your first.

Comment: As a beginner in physics I'm wondering if those are the same or what's the difference? @Drjh

Comment: @Drjh Is the other one average velocity and the other average speed?

Comment: If you did not understand my last comment, please tell me which part is worrying you.

Comment: Yes. The first one is average speed and the second one is average velocity.

Comment: For example someone walks 10 meters to the left and 12 meters to the right in 20 seconds. Which formula should i use to calculate the average speed and which to use when calculating average velocity? @Drjh

Comment: Note, as in one of my earlier comments, one is a scalar (no direction, just magnitude) _speed_, and the second is a vector (magnitude and direction), _velocity_.

Comment: But are both velocity?

Comment: What does the question ask you to calculate? Speed or velocity? Whenever it’s speed, you do not include direction. Whenever it’s velocity, you do.

Comment: No, I mean what does the v stand for?

Comment: @James0987 $v$ is average speed and $\vec v$ is average velocity. The first is a scalar and the second is a vector. And unless the path is a straight line, they will not generally have the same magnitude - see the example in my answer.

Comment: If you see $\vec v$ then velocity, and just $v$ means speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing in your first you you mean $\frac{\Delta S}{\Delta t}$. If this is the case then the difference would be in that you seem to use vector notation in the second equation and not in the first one. This means that in the first one you talk about the speed of something, i.e. that rate at which it moves. In the second one, since there is also a vector-notation involved, this would indicate that here you have a vector with a direction and magnitude, the magnitude representing the value from the first equation, the rate of change in position, and the direction being the direction in which this change is happening.

Think if it as the first one is saying "We are moving at 2m/s", and the second one saying "we are moving at 2m/s to the left" or something like that.

Other than the direction-component to my answers, the equations represent the same thing. They both essentially say $\frac{\text{how much we have moved}}{\text{the time it took us to move this distance}}$ with the second one having added in which direction we moved as well.

**Speed is rate of movement, velocity is rate of movement in a certain direction.**

Comment: I mean in my book it doesn't say Delta s. I don't know why?

Comment: The delta is not crucial, therfore it was probably omitted. It would still represent the distance. I guess here $S = S_2 - S_2$. Or anything that symbolises a distance travelled.It could also be a typo. We will never know. But I'm 100% certain that the equations are depicting speed and velocity, i.e presenting that they are two different things.

Comment: Ok, thank you! One question more. When will the velocity be positive or negative? If i move up will it be negative and vice versa?

Comment: Depends on the notation you use. Either it can be that you move $-2\hat{x}$ or you move  $2\left(\hat{-x}\right)$. (If x-direction is the direction in which you move). $\hat{x}$ represents a unit vector in a direction. I.e it is a vector in direction $x$ of length 1.

Comment: So basically, I will understand it when i learn about vectors in math?

Comment: @James0987 Definetly. Or since your material seems to go through this now, I'd say pretty soon. If you're happy with the answer you can mark it as solved. Or wait until a bettero ne comes along.

Answer (score 2):

The first expression $\frac s {\Delta t}$ is the average speed over the interval $\Delta t$ and the second $\frac {\Delta \vec x}{\Delta t}$ is the average velocity over the same interval.

The difference is that if I travel around a circle with circumference $10$ metres in $5$ seconds then my average speed is $\frac {10} 5=2$ metres per second, but my average velocity is zero because $\Delta \vec x=0$ since I finish where I started.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of speed - instantaneous and average. Average is defined as, total displacement over time period :
$$ \overline v = \frac {\Delta x}{\Delta t} $$

By definition, instant speed is average speed when time period goes to zero :

$$ v = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \overline v = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac {\Delta x}{\Delta t} = \frac {dx}{dt} $$

**EDIT**

As about your direct question =>
$$\begin{align}
\overline v 
&= \frac 1N \left( \frac{\Delta x_1}{\Delta t} + \frac{\Delta x_2}{\Delta t} + \ldots  + \frac{\Delta x_n}{\Delta t} \right)
\\&=\frac {1}{\Delta t} \left( \frac{\Delta x_1}{N} + \frac{\Delta x_2}{N} + \ldots  + \frac{\Delta x_n}{N} \right)
\\&=\frac {\overline {\Delta x}}{\Delta t}
\\&= \frac{\Delta x_1}{N\Delta t} + \frac{\Delta x_2}{N\Delta t} + \ldots  + \frac{\Delta x_n}{N\Delta t}
\\&=\frac {\Delta x_1 + \Delta x_2 + \ldots + \Delta x_n}{N \Delta t}
\\&=\frac {\Delta s}{\tau}
\end{align}
$$

Thus, your both given definitions **are equivalent**.

Comment: This is OK but it is not what OP asked for.

Comment: I've edited my answer for both definition analysis, please check my edit.